# virtualenv returns error 'Operation not Permitted'

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I was using the command `virtualenv --no-site-packages django-env` but I encountered the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==12.0.7', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 985, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1416, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

So I thought using the command `sudo virtualenv --no-site-packages django-env` on my terminal to avoid any operating system conflicts, but it throws the following error please have a look at that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==12.0.7', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 985, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1204, in install_python
    copyfile(stdinc_dir, inc_dir, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 479, in copyfile
    copyfileordir(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 454, in copyfileordir
    shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
shutil.Error: [('/usr/include/python2.7/numpy', 'django-env/include/python2.7/numpy', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted')]
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6

I am unable to figure what is causing the error.

Comment: Why are you running it using sudo? You really don't need to do that.

Comment: I was running without ``sudo`` but this error came
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==12.0.7', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: wait I am updating the question either

Comment: How you install virtualenv? As I see it's probably by pip or easy_install. Did you upgrade your ubuntu from older one and the virtualenv was installed on the older one?

Comment: The issue was not with the Ubuntu , I have found it out it was the problem of the USb drive , I have to provide the media ownership then only it would work on the device.

Answer (score 6):

By default, VirtualBox will forbid creating symlinks in mounted shared folders due to the security reasons.

You can however, enable it yourself manually using the following command.

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

After that virtual environment should be bootstrapped correctly. Do not forget to shutdown the VM for this setting to be picked up.

You can refer to this VirtualBox's ticket for more details: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085.

Comment: seems to need a reboot of the vbox but this worked for me Virtualbox 6.1 on Mac + Ubuntu 20 client

Answer (score 5):

Regarding ownership of the development folder:

I had a similar error when running virtualenv on a virtualbox mounted drive. Switching over to a directory on the virtual machine ran fine.

All the best.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when running virtualenv on a mounted drive. For me "--always-copy" option resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using venv module (like you're supposed to nowadays), create the virtual environment in some nonshared folder. The stupid feature of that module is even if you specify `--copies` flag, it still tries to create symlinks, but between two folders in the same directory.

Create the virutal environment in a non-shared folder between your vm and host, remove the symlink and duplicate the lib folder via copy or another command.

Answer (score 0):

On your home try these commands

1.sudo easy_install virtualenv
2.mkdir virt_env
3.virtualenv virt_env/test1 
4.source  test1/bin/activate
5.pip install django==1.7.4

after that
django-admin.py startproject project_name